# Function running without being called?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple countdown timer that turns into a button once hitting 0. My function executes without being called. What am I doing wrong here? If possible, I would like to be told how to "hide" the counter once my button is displayed as well.

```js
var count = 2;
var counter = setInterval(func1, 1000);


function func1() {
  count = count - 1;
  if (count <= -1) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    var btn = document.createElement("Button");
    btn.innerHTML = "New Timer";
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("func1").innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<span id="func1"></span>
```

Comment: u call the function in setInterval

Comment: `setInterval` sets up the function to be called later...

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(btn); document.getElementById("func1").style.display="none"`

Answer (score 0):

You already call the function inside `setInterval` 
When u mention a function name inside `setInterval` you dont have to add `()` to call it . `setInterval()` method will execute the function automatically in your given time

updated answer

suppose this is ur function function test() {} if u call this function test() its means u are calling a function and call this test mean u assign a function in setInterval method we asssign a function test and after the certain time its being called easy way to understand its add Parentheses or () in ur function like this test() hope its clear now

new updated answer

```
<button onclick="func1">start</button>
<span id="func1"></span>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var count = 2;
  var counter = setInterval(func1, 1000);
  function func1() { 
    count = count-1;
    if (count <= -1) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      var btn = document.createElement("Button");
      btn.innerHTML = "New Timer";
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
      return;
    }
    document.getElementById("func1").innerHTML=count;
  }
});
<script>
```

Comment: So would this mean I am changing var counter = setInterval(func1,1000); in to var counter = setInterval func1,1000;? Sorry, I am very new to coding.

Comment: no bro you  misunderstand me. writting this `var counter = setInterval func1,1000` will give you syntax error
i update my answer plz check . hope it will help u to better understand

Comment: So how would I stop setInterval from executing before I want it to?

Comment: u can use `clearInterval()`
u can this one this is really helpful https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

let me know if u need anything more

Comment: I already have the clearInterval() within my function, I am asking how to change my code to prevent the setInterval from executing right when I load the page.

Comment: if you wanna use pure javascript use this 
`$(window).load(function () { alert("hello");});` else if u use jquery  u can try this 
`$(function(){alert("hello");});`
inform me if its work

Comment: $(window).load(function func1(){
so it would be like this?

Comment: $(window).load(function () { alert("hello");
        count = count-1; //... function won't execute at all now

Comment: where is ur closing ?
`$(window).load(function () { 
  alert("hello")
  count = count-1;
})`

Comment: This is only a part of the code, I did not want to comment the entire block of text.

Comment: can u create a codepen its hard to solve ur problem this way

Comment: I don't see anything